# Where to place AdMob banner?

Tags: java, android, admob

I am about to implement `AdMob` banner into my application with 1000 active users.

I have 1 `main Activity` with 5 `fragments` inside, each `fragment` represents different tab.

Shall I use 1 main banner on main activity that is holding these fragments or should I use different banner on each fragment?

Remember, I am making decision on best earning solution. Can I get more money on 5 banners each on his own banner? `AdMob` does give a little for `impresions`.

Answer (score 1):

You should place ads in mainactivity to make the ads not request a new ads again. If u choose to put ads on every each fragment, it just only make your apps take much data that make user run it slow if they have many task. And also you can prevent the ads from invalid click.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting only one banner into one Activity. It can be placed outside of any fragment. It is better for user and developer. For the user: lesser internet connections, a lesser number of lags, better UI.
For you: only a click of a user gives to you the money. But if you increase the number of downloaded banners it obviously decreases eCPM. BTW, it improves the UI test too, lesser memory usage, etc.